# Using module with both class and instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

In my application I need to call the same methods on the collection of the objects and on separate object as well. For example, an insured user has many insurance policies, which can change their state from draft to accepted, etc. For my report I need to get statistics about all policies states for separate user for particular date. But if checkbox "Show me policies for all the users" was set, I need to grab data from the whole collection of users, iterating each of them and collecting policies states information for the particular date. My question is - what are best practices for such cases? Where should I put such methods, can I combine them into one?

Comment: You question might be a bit too generic. Can you add some code from the models and a concrete example what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by placing both class and instance methods (with the same names) into the same module file. Please see the example below:

```
require 'active_support/concern'    
module SharedMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def get_policies(date)
      self.all.each do |entity|
        entity.get_policies(date)
      end
    end
  end

  #Instance methods
  def get_policies(date)
    self.find_policy #place required code here
  end
end
```

After that I need to include this module in my models and I can call get_policies(date) both as class and instance method. Please follow the link to get more information http://alexanderwong.me/post/15697487692/rails-model-mixins-via-included-modules